# App Invites is deprecated

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-app-invites

I am developing one application which has appinvite functionality but after pod update i got below below error

> 'show(from:with:delegate:)' is deprecated: App Invites no longer supported

After that i goto the facebook developer site and found below text on top

> With the release of the Facebook SDK version 4.28.0, App Invites is deprecated. It will be supported until February 5, 2018. ([link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/ios))

Is there any other way to invite on facebook after app invite stop support for non game application in ios?

Answer (score 2):

Chirag,
Once app invites are deprecated there is no other way to invite on Facebook unless you allow sharing on users' FB timeline with tracking/attribution links.

As an app developer, you should also consider using popular messaging apps and other social networks to leverage app invites i.e Whatsapp, Kik, Twitter, Kakao etc. [More details here](https://blog.getsocial.im/facebook-deprecates-app-invites-are-you-ready/)

*(Disclaimer: I am the founder of GetSocial)*